# How to customize execution key in spring web flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I'm trying to change the spring web flow url to hide the execution parameter inside the path. I created my own FlowUrlHandler that appends the execution and snapshot values as last elements of the path, but when I try to use the app if fails when I start the flow because is says that the key is in incorrect format (does not look like e1s1). I debuged down to FlowExecutionKeyFactory which seems to do what I need to adapt, but I cannot figure out a way how to customize this via java config.
Here is my webflow configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebflowConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFacotryBean;

  @Bean
  public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
    return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder() //
        .setBasePath("classpath:flows") //
        .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml") //
        .setFlowBuilderServices(this.flowBuilderServices()) //
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
    return getFlowExecutorBuilder(this.flowRegistry()) //
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder() //
        .setViewFactoryCreator(this.mvcViewFactoryCreator()) // Important!
        .setValidator(this.localValidatorFacotryBean).build();
  }
  // ----------------------------------------------------------

  @Bean
  public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
    final FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
    handlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(this.flowRegistry());
    return handlerMapping;
  }

  @Bean
  public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
    final FlowHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
    handlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(this.flowExecutor());
    handlerAdapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);
    handlerAdapter.setFlowUrlHandler(pathBasedFlowUrlHandler());
    return handlerAdapter;
  }

  @Bean
  public FlowUrlHandler pathBasedFlowUrlHandler() {
    return new PathBasedFlowUrlHandler();
  }

  @Bean
  public ViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator() {
    final MvcViewFactoryCreator factoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
    factoryCreator.setViewResolvers(Collections.singletonList(this.thymeleafViewResolver()));
    factoryCreator.setUseSpringBeanBinding(true);
    return factoryCreator;
  }

  @Bean
  @Description("Thymeleaf AJAX view resolver for Spring WebFlow")
  public AjaxThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    final AjaxThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new AjaxThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(FlowAjaxThymeleafView.class);
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(this.templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return viewResolver;
  }

  @Bean
  @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
  public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return templateResolver;
  }

  @Bean
  @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(this.templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
  }


}
```